# Understanding Hyperledger Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am currently getting started with Hyperledger Fabric and have some issues understanding some of the concepts. I have no idea whether this post belongs here, but: I managed to set up a network using the tutorials, wrote some chaincode in Go and I know how to query it from the CLI. But there still are a couple of things that I simply don't understand even about the parts that I managed to get done.

1. If I'm correct, the peers and the ordering service are all running locally on my machine, in different threads, maybe in their own docker containers or whatever, but: How would I go about setting this up as a real network? Let's say I wanted to simulate an entire network locally using a couple of laptops. What would I need to do in order to make that work? Is that even possible? Where can I find information on this stuff?
2. What exactly does the MSP do? Could you point me to a resource where I can read up on the certificates and all of that stuff? I haven't worked with those things before and don't know a lot, but I'm willing to learn.
3. Can I use the Java SDK to build apps that users would use to interact with the network? Or is my understanding of the relationship between the SDK and the network wrong? How would one go about sending a query to the peers, how would one address them? (I'm currently struggling with even installing the SDK, but I think that belongs into its own question.)

Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Have you got it working?

Answer (score 1):

1. Of course you can run fabric in a distributed network across different hosts. You can either deploy it on docker swarm or on kubernetes, or you can just run it on bare metal across different machines. You can ask around in the https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/deployment
2. Yes, we have excellent documentation for that! See [1] [2] [3]
3. The idea is that you have fabric nodes (orderers and peers) running, and your application written in some languages (i.e java) does anything you can think of, such as - being a web server, or a web client, etc. but in the end - it interacts with the blockchain via interacting with the peers and orderers via the client SDK.

[1] https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html

[2] https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/identity/identity.html

[3] https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/membership/membership.html